For the below query I'm getting System.queryexception: only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL. Please find the below code for refer
global with sharing class VIA_B2B_RecordSharing_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
  private final String query;
  private final String objectName;
  private final String shareObjectName;
  private final String accountFieldName;
  private final Schema.SObjectType shareSObjectType;
  private final String sharingMode;
  private final String scopeWhereClause;
  private final Map<String, String> shareObjectFieldNames;

  public static final String SHARE_REASON = 'Manual';
  public static final String SHARE_ACCESS_LEVEL = 'Read';

  public VIA_B2B_RecordSharing_Batch(
    String objectName,
    String accountFieldName,
    String shareObjectName,
    String sharingMode,
    String scopeWhereClause
  ) {
    if (
      String.isBlank(objectName) ||
      String.isBlank(accountFieldName) ||
      String.isBlank(shareObjectName) ||
      String.isBlank(scopeWhereClause)
    ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        'objectName, accountFieldName, shareObjectName and scopeWhereClause are required'
      );
    }

    if (
      String.isBlank(sharingMode) ||
      (sharingMode != 'Hospital' &&
      sharingMode != 'Pharma')
    ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        'sharingMode must be either "Hospital" or "Pharma"'
      );
    }

    this.objectName = objectName;
    this.accountFieldName = accountFieldName;
    this.shareObjectName = shareObjectName;
    this.shareSObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
      .get(this.shareObjectName);
    this.sharingMode = sharingMode;
    this.scopeWhereClause = scopeWhereClause;

    if (this.accountFieldName != 'Id') {
      this.query =
        'SELECT Id,' +
        this.accountFieldName +
        ' FROM ' +
        this.objectName +
        ' WHERE ' +
        this.scopeWhereClause;
    } else {
      this.query =
        'SELECT Id' +
        ' FROM ' +
        this.objectName +
        ' WHERE ' +
        this.scopeWhereClause;
    }
    System.debug('this.query --> ' + this.query);
@InvocableMethod(label='Run B2B record sharing batch for a particular object')
  public static void runJob(Request[] inputs) {
    Database.executeBatch(
      new VIA_B2B_RecordSharing_Batch(
        inputs[0].objectName,
        inputs[0].accountFieldName,
        inputs[0].shareObjectName,
        inputs[0].sharingMode,
        inputs[0].scopeWhereClause
      )
    );
  }

  public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='objectName'
      description='The object to share'
      required=true
    )
    public String objectName;
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='accountFieldName'
      description='The account field on the object to share'
      required=true
    )
    public String accountFieldName;
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='shareObjectName'
      description='The share object for the object'
      required=true
    )
    public String shareObjectName;
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='sharingMode'
      description='Hospital or Pharma'
      required=true
    )
    public String sharingMode;
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='scopeWhereClause'
      description='The WHERE clause to restrict the batch scope'
      required=true
    )
    public String scopeWhereClause;
  }

Please find the above code where the variables used in the code are set to
The queries generated are:

SELECT Id,Account_vod__c FROM Order_vod__c WHERE Account_vod__r.MYL_Distribution_Channel__c = '05' AND EPD_Country_Code__c = 'FR' AND RecordType.DeveloperName NOT IN('Vaccine','EPD_IBE_Platform')


SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'B2B Portal Hospital'


Can you post your full batch code?

Or at least the variables used in the code you have included, along with the values they are set to.

What's the actual query it's generating?  ie. what does System.debug('this.query --> ' + this.query); give you?

Below is the debug:20:03:53:871 USER_DEBUG [78]|DEBUG|this.query --> SELECT Id,Account_vod__c FROM Order_vod__c WHERE Account_vod__r.MYL_Distribution_Channel__c = '05' AND EPD_Country_Code__c = 'FR' AND RecordType.DeveloperName NOT IN('Vaccine','EPD_IBE_Platform')
20:03:53:957 USER_DEBUG [78]|DEBUG|this.query --> SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'B2B Portal Hospital'

@NickC this is the debug log I get 78]|DEBUG|this.query --> SELECT Id,Account_vod__c FROM Order_vod__c WHERE Account_vod__r.MYL_Distribution_Channel__c = '05' AND EPD_Country_Code__c = 'FR' AND RecordType.DeveloperName NOT IN('Vaccine','EPD_IBE_Platform') 20:03:53:957 USER_DEBUG [78]|DEBUG|this.query --> SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'B2B Portal Hospital'

@Aishwarya  For future reference, please edit your question to add more detail like this

IS this the full code? Does this even compile?

No it's not the full code

@NickC It seems like the error in query this.query on how it is concatenating. I'm getting error as System.QueryException : only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL

You are missing a space between IN and the left parenthesis
